# Order of growth of following function

Tags: big-o

Can someone tell me if the ranking of following functions by order of growth is correct ? (increasing to decreasing)

> 2^n, n^2, (nlgn, lg(n!)), n^(1/lgn), 4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of these are right. However, look at

> n<sup>1/lg n</sup>.

Notice that, for nonzero n, we have n = 2<sup>lg n</sup>, so

> n<sup>1/lg n</sup> = (2<sup>lg n</sup>)<sup>1/lg n</sup> = 2<sup>lg n / lg n</sup> = 2<sup>1</sup> = 2.

So while 2 and 4 do grow at the same (nonexistent) rate, n<sup>1/lg n</sup> is always smaller than 4 for any nonzero n.